# Reading File Assets for Tests in IntelliJ Android Application

Tags: android, file-io, junit, intellij-idea

I don't think this is an IntelliJ issue specifically but giving all the details regardless.  I created an Android Test Application in IntelliJ 13 and I'm trying to test some existing code in an Android application.  This bit of code accepts an InputStream which is a JSON file to be read.  I am trying to test a method for reading this file InputStream.  I have the following:

My project structure looks like this:

```
android_test
- libs
- res
- src
- testAssetes
  - file.json
```

And my test method is:

```
public void testParseFile() {
  FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File("./testAssets/file.json"));
  // code continues..
}
```

I keep getting a FileNotFound exception.  I've also tried the following:

```
android_test
- libs
- res
- src
  - com
    - test
      - file.json
```

And then my code is modified to:

```
InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/com/test/file.json")
```

And in this case, the InputStream is always null.  I created a regular java project with similar code and it worked just fine. Not sure if it has something to do with how the InstrumentTestRunner is working or what the deal is.

UPDATE: I just realized that the problem is probably because these tests are running with the InstrumentationTestRunner which executes on the emulator/device.  So I think what I need to know is how to get my test file on to that file system and read it in for a test.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the `android_test` directory as the "Working directory" in IntelliJ via "Run >  Edit Configurations"

Comment: Hm, ok.  But what about when these tests are being ran from Ant or adb?

Comment: If you start the `ant test` from `android_test`, then `android_test` will be the `pwd`

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to use a bit of reflection. A utility method I use is :

```
public String assetFileContents(final String fileName) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
    InputStream fileStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader()
            .getResourceAsStream("assets/" + fileName);

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileStream));
    String line;
    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        text.append(line);
    }
    return text.toString();
}
```

This return the `String` content of `fileName`. Also, I keep the test files in `assets` folder at `/src/tests/assets` (set via `assets.srcDir` in `build.gradle`, I think default has `instrumentTests` instead of `tests`)

I don't think the `InstrumentTestRunner` argument is relevant. As long as it's in the source path folders it should be packaged along with the app.

To see running examples using test files, see my repository [here](https://github.com/sfarooq/android-google-spreadsheets-api/tree/gradle) (FYI, I'm currently refactoring the project, they might have moved to another branch at a later point).

Comment: This method doesn't work if you're using pure java i.e. a non-Android unit test case, for this reason: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=64887#c7